# Pages of text on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I need to print a lot of text to something on a JPanel in a way that allows the text to be broken up into pages. When I run the code, it looks like this:
[image]

My code currently creates a JPanel and adds a JTextArea to the JPanel with text called from another class. Does anyone know of a method I could use to break up the text into pages? Thanks

Comment: *"Does anyone know of a method I could use to break up the text into pages?"* A `JScrollPane` (wrapped around the `JTextArea`) is good for this type of requirement. In fact, on a computer screen, a scroll works better than 'pages' as appear in a physical book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try breaking text into array of lines and then display pre defined number of lines as a page. Change start and end line numbers based on click of Page Up or Page down click.

```
String lines[] = text.split("\\r?\\n");
```

Comment: Thanks! I used a for loop to append the strings to the JTextArea, but they're all printing on a single line now.

Comment: If you are putting text in JLabel object, wrap text in html tags. For example <html>sample text</html>